# Open expression in Python for a text file with unknown extension but same layout of the data inside of it

Tags: python, file-io, file-processing

I am writing a script in python that will read in data from a text file and perform various operations on the data. It is working perfectly if I specify the extension of my file in this statement `with open("file.txt") as f:`. My question is (and I don't even know if this is possible), I have to open a file that someone will provide to me but I let's assume that they will all provide it with different extensions (.txt, .rtf, .odt, .doc). All of the files will have the same layout which is for example:

14
Lucas,13
Markus,7
Peter,4

So essentially:

```
integer
string,integer
string,integer
string,integer
```

Is there a way to set the extension in `with open("file.txt") as f:` to something like `with open("file.*") as f:` that will process all the text files apart from their extension, given they have all the same layout.

Comment: The problem with `.rtf`, `.doc`, etc. files is that they're **NOT** text files. They may look the same on screen when viewing them with the correct program, but if you were to open them in a plain text editor, you'd see what their contents really are...

Comment: @MattDMo I think those were just examples.

Comment: @OP: Take a look at `os.walk()` and other directory listing features in the `os` module.

Comment: The `glob` module may also help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `open` a full path. The extension may have signification on Windows, but this is just an artifact, it is actually part of the file name. However, you can use [listdir](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir) and [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/fnmatch.html?highlight=fnmatch#fnmatch.fnmatch) to get all files in a directory matching a specific pattern.

Or as Wooble said, you can use the glob module. The following example takes a path, removes the extension to replace it with a star and create a search pattern for glob. Then it uses glob to get a list of matching files and loops over all files to apply whatever algorithm you want.

```py
>>> import glob
>>> import os.path
>>> path = "/tmp/test.txt"
>>> root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
>>> pattern = root + ".*"
>>> list_of_files = glob.glob(pattern)
>>> list_of_files
['/tmp/test.rtf', '/tmp/test.txt']
>>> for f in list_of_files:
        with open(f, "r") as ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality can be implemented using th `glob` module.

```
import glob
print glob.glob('*.*')
```

**Will print every file in the directory.**

```
import glob
print glob.glob('*.txt')
```

**Will print every text file in the directory.**

### The one you are looking for is :

```
import glob
print glob.glob('name_of_the_file.*')
```

**So you can do :**

```
    import glob
    for i in glob.glob('name_of_the_file.*') :
        with open(i) as f :
      # do operations
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround. May not work in some cases. What I am trying to do is get list of all the files and search for required name.

```
file_name='YOUR_FILE_NAME'+'.'
l=os.listdir(PATH_TO_FILE)
for f in l:
    if f.startswith(file_name):
        fname=f
with open(fname) as f:
    #perform operation
```